# UTC time or local time stored in data store

Tags: c#, azure, database-design, architecture, azure-storage

I have an appliation that imports user-provided Excel file that is uploaded into Azure Block storage, and processes the data via Azure Functions (in C#), finally saves the data into Azure Table (like a database table).

The Excel file contains time columns which are in London time. The users of the application are UK based only.

In this case, should the times in Excel file be converted to UTC time or the origial time when it is saved into Azure Table?

In general, what factors determine that a time must be saved in UTC time or local time?

**UPDATE**

The Azure Functions is hosted in North Europe.

By default, it seems that Azure Table auto-saves DateTimeOffset in UTC time. That is, "6/2/2020 9:00:00 PM +01:00" is saved as 8pm instead of 9pm.

Simiarly, when Azure Functions time zone is set to "WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE": "GMT Standard Time", "6/2/2020 9:00:00 PM +01:00" is saved as 8pm instead of 9pm

Comment: If you're working with one specific location, better use local time. Simple is better.

Comment: Just make sure the timestamps are all relative to the **same** timezone. Do not mix the time zones. UTC, well, is universal, so it's certainly not bad to use it as the timezone for all timestamps. But if you can convert it when loading the data, that means that you can also convert it later, should you need it in UTC. So you don't really lose anything. Unless you frequently need UTC of course. Then converting it once and use it often may come a little cheaper. Same goes for any other timezone you'll use the most though.

Answer (score 0):

It is always best practice to store dates and times in UTC format wherever possible. If in the future the data is being returned to another application you will run into headaches converting all times back to UTC (most software companies will be using UTC as best practice).

If it is a small scale application you may be unlikely to run into this problem in which case using local time would suffice, however you should consider both options.

Comment: Please could you elaborate on "If in the future the data is being returned to another application you will run into headaches converting all times back to UTC". The application currently stores times in UTC format, why does it convert back to UTC?

Comment: We ran into an issue where we stored timestamps in local time in our system (these were present across multiple tables in the database). When we integrated with Salesforce they needed to call our api which would return a different time to what they had (as they used UTC). The outcome was a major data cleanup and an "I wish we stored it as UTC to begin with" moment.

Comment: "It is always best practice to store dates and times in UTC format wherever possible. " I beg the differ. Dates and times is a far more complicated concept than most of us realize, and there are many things to consider before going full UTC for a localized application, especially if the dates in question are future dates.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that the practice to store UTC wherever possible is **assumed to be** best practice just because it **mostly works**.

But there can be cases [**when it doesn't**](http://www.creativedeletion.com/2015/03/19/persisting_future_datetimes.html). If you want to surprise yourself with things you did not know about time, see [this](http://www.creativedeletion.com/2015/01/28/falsehoods-programmers-date-time-zones.html).

Hence, dont just blindly go with storing datetime in UTC *because you read it somewhere*. Understand the risks and make sure your application is either not affected or business can accept any risks before you move forward.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973825(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) are the best practices from Microsoft about using Datetime in the .Net framework (note, the article is a bit old but still has value).